# Arduino Python3 script

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, arduino, pyserial

I'm trying to use a Python3 script to control an Arduino Mega. This is a simple script to take a line from the keyboard and echo it back through the Arduino. I started with a working Python 2 script from http://petrimaki.wordpress.com/2013/04/28/reading-arduino-serial-ports-in-windows-7/. I can't seem to get the characters I sent back, which is probably a formatting issue.

Is this a formatting issue? unicode to ASCII issue?
How do I read/write binary/hex data and ASCII text with Python 3 and pySerial?
Any advice for a Python newbie is welcome.

Python 3 script:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM8', 9600, timeout=0)
var = input("Enter something: ")
print(var)
ser.write(bytes(var.encode('ascii')))
while 1:
    try:
        print(ser.readline())
        time.sleep(1)
    except ser.SerialTimeoutException:
        print(('Data could not be read'))
```

Arduino code:

```
int incomingByte=0;

void setup() {
  // Open serial connection.
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // Read the incoming byte.
    incomingByte = Serial.read();

    // Echo what you got.
    Serial.print("I got: ");
    Serial.println(incomingByte);
  }
}
```

Input:
The quick red fox

Output:

```
b''
b'I got: 84\r\n'
b'I got: 104\r\n'
b'I got: 101\r\n'
```

and so on.

Comment: You are receiving the message, they're just printing the codepoint instead the character. ASCII 84 is `T`, 104 is `h`, 101 is `e`.

Comment: Do you know the syntax to get ASCII back?

Answer (score 1):

`bytes(var.encode('ascii'))` seems unnecessary, just use the `.encode()` method or the `bytes()` function, no need for both. You can also use `.decode()` on the data that you receive.

The exception `serial.SerialTimeoutException` is [raised on write timeouts](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.SerialTimeoutException), nothing to do with reading.

In the Arduino code, try using [Serial.write()](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Write) to send the data back.